# How to ISOLATE ports on a TP-LINK TL-SG1024DE

Tags: switch

[image: Current VLAN Configuration]

I would like to make switch ports 15,16,17,18 like they are their own switch that will pass all traffic among each other, ports 15,16,17,18 as if it was a 4-port switch all on its own.

What is recommended?

Comment: Unfortunately, for questions about hardware, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support, but TP-Link does not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new VLAN, with Ports 15-19 aus untagged members, ensure there ist no bridging or routing enabled for that VLAN to/from all the other ones, also no proxy-arp or anything like that. That should be all to do...

Comment: It doesn't have any routing capabilities. I didn't see any options for Proxy ARP either.

Comment: Something like: